# React TypeScript how to pass property to child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to pass props to my component, but I do not seem to be able to pass the 'Commune' because it has an name property.

any idea how I do pass Commune.name as a prop to my component ?

These are my interfaces,

```
interface Base {
       Titre: string,
       TextComplet: string,
       DateDebut: string
       DateFin: string,
       Commune: Commune,
       Image: Blob | undefined,  
    }

export interface Info extends Base  {
   TextPreview: string,
}

export interface Commune{
    Id?: number,
    name: string
}
```

This is my component where i want to pass the props

```
<Preview Commune={Commune[0].name} Titre={Titre} TextComplet={Text_Complet} DateDebut={Date_Debut} DateFin={Date_Fin} TextPreview={Text_Preview} ></Preview>
```

This is the error I keep getting

[image]

Comment: You have to pass object with ```name``` property to ```Comune``` property of the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @nicholas-tower said that I can pass the whole object, so without changing the code I can pass it like this

```
<Preview Commune={{name: Commune[0].name, Id: Commune[0].Id}} Titre={Titre} TextComplet={Text_Complet} DateDebut={Date_Debut} DateFin={Date_Fin} TextPreview={Text_Preview} ></Preview>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass just the name, then change the type on the prop to be a string:

```
interface Base {
  Titre: string,
  TextComplet: string,
  DateDebut: string
  DateFin: string,
  Commune: string, // <---- changed this line
  Image: Blob | undefined,  
}
```

If you want to pass the entire commune object, then your type is fine, but you need to change your code to pass the entire object:

```
<Preview Commune={Commune[0]} /* etc */ />
```

Comment: thank you for pointing out that I can pass the whole object to Commune